# How to contact Package Index Owner on PyPI when there is no Home Page?

Tags: website

I'd like to report problem with [`quartz` package on `pypi.python.org`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/quartz), but I cannot find any option to contact the package index owner in order to report a bug (problem with the package). In other packages I can see Home Page or other links, in this package there are no any links.

What's the normal procedure to contact the author of the Python package hosted on the Python Package Index?

Comment: I don't consider PyPi to be a web application in the traditional sense.  I think this is somewhat useful information, but I'm not sure where it belongs on SE

Answer (score 1):

As per response from [Jason](https://github.com/jamadden) at [GitHub issue page](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues/647):

> Try here: https://github.com/vladcalin/quartz
>
> If the `pypi.python.org` page doesn't directly list enough information to find the maintainers, you'll have to look for yourself. In some cases, if you download and unpack the sdist it will include a `README` file or some other information not published to PyPI.
>
> In other cases, you can try looking for other packages the user has published to PyPI. I did that by going to https://pypi.org/user/vcalin/. Then look at the other packages for URLs; I was easily able to find the github account for this user from those other packages, and from there it was easy to find the quartz repository.
>
> In the worst case scenario you'll just have to resort to some web searches.